# Dragon tree yellow leaves

Tags: houseplants, leaves, tree-care, dracaena

I have a few yellow leaves with some brown spots. The rest of the plant looks ok, close to the window, water once a week (sometimes fresh water from tap, sometimes I let the water stay overnight before using it). Any ideas? I'm not very good with plants.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a sign of nutrient deprivation, in other words it can use some fertilizer. How often do you fertilize it? I think because of spring it wants to grow and needs some extra nutrients therefore.

Comment: I still didn't fertilized, bought it not long ago. Ok, I'll try to give it some food and we'll see. Thank you